# Circular dependency problems when using Sidekiq and module naming schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload, sidekiq

Good morning, we're having annoying issues when using Sidekiq to process our queues. The problem seems to happen the first time we execute Sidekiq (eager loads resources) and on production environments.

basically we have our classes separated within modules to have a better naming schema.

This is an example module were the problem occurs

```
module MyApp
  module APIIntegration
    class Client          
       def driver
         @driver ||= MyApp::APIIntegration::Driver.new
       end  
    end
  end
end
```

We're getting "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MyApp::APIIntegration::Driver"

Any idea why this is happening? should we refer the driver by just calling Driver instead of the fully qualified name? What can I try to reproduce this problem?

Any suggestion is welcome, and thanks a lot

Comment: can you show the code of Driver Module/Class and the path where these files are placed?

Comment: this is not a circular dependency problem. it is because of the naming of modules and the location of files

Comment: they are both at the same level. something like /lib/my_app/api_integration/client.rb and /lib/my_app/api_integration/driver.rb

Comment: 1. `module APIIntegration` should be `module ApiIntegration` 2. `@driver ||= MyApp::APIIntegration::Driver.new` to `@driver ||= Driver.new`

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
module MyApp
  module APIIntegration
    class Client          
       def driver
         @driver ||= Driver.new
       end  
    end
  end
end
```